# Get Customers by a specific date range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to query out customers that placed an order between two dates, but they haven’t ordered before, and also not thereafter…

That’s the query I made, I think the result is correct, but I wonder if there’s a cleaner way of getting the desired query.

```
SELECT c.customerno 
from Customer c 
WHERE c.CustomerID in
                  (SELECT t.CustomerID 
                  from [Transaction] t 
                  WHERE 
                    (t.StartSaleTime  between '2/25/2013' And '04/03/2013') 
                  or t.StartSaleTime  between '2/25/2014' And '04/03/2014')
AND c.CustomerID not in 
                     (SELECT t.CustomerID 
                     from [Transaction] t 
                     WHERE t.StartSaleTime < '2/25/2013')
AND c.CustomerID not in 
                     (SELECT t.CustomerID 
                     from [Transaction] t 
                     WHERE t.StartSaleTime > '04/03/2013')
```

EDIT: The request was modified to also include an other date range, that makes it way more complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query seems correct, but the second and third subquery can be merge into one. Also, I don't know the exact datatype of `StartSaleTime`, but if it's a `DATETIME` then you should avoid using `BETWEEN`. Anyway, you could do:

```
SELECT c.customerno 
FROM Customer c 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [Transaction]
             WHERE StartSaleTime BETWEEN '2/25/2013' AND '04/03/2013'
             AND CustomerID = c.CustomerID)
AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM [Transaction]
                WHERE CustomerID = c.CustomerID
                AND (StartSaleTime < '2/25/2013' 
                  OR StartSaleTime > '04/03/2013'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see my Edit, if possible to modify the query it will be much appreciated. (StartSaleTime is a dateTime type.)

Comment: @Ezi I don't see any edit of the code of your query, nor another date range

Comment: sorry I added the info now.

Comment: @Ezi And why is it more complicated now?, do you want customers that have a transaction inside both date ranges, but not outside of them?.

Comment: That's correct. The first part of the query is simple but how to I exclude all times not in that range...

Comment: @Ezi It's not more complicated, although unconventional you **can** use `NOT BETWEEN`. So, `EXISTS(.......WHERE StartSaleTime BETWEEN '2/25/2013' AND '04/03/2013' OR StartSaleTime  BETWEEN '2/25/2014' And '04/03/2014'.....)` and `NOT EXISTS(.....WHERE StartSaleTime NOT BETWEEN '2/25/2013' AND '04/03/2013' AND StartSaleTime  NOT BETWEEN '2/25/2014' AND '04/03/2014'.....)`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c.customerno 
from Customer c INNER JOIN [Transaction] t
ON C.CustomerID  = t.CustomerID 
WHERE t.StartSaleTime >= '2/25/2013' 
AND   t.StartSaleTime <= '04/03/2013'
AND NOT EXISTS
             (SELECT 1 
              from [Transaction]  
              WHERE StartSaleTime < '2/25/2013'
              AND CustomerID = C.CustomerID)
AND NOT EXISTS
             (SELECT 1 
              from [Transaction]  
              WHERE StartSaleTime > '04/03/2013'
              AND CustomerID = C.CustomerID)
```

Also avoid using `BETWEEN` operator with dates. The reason why read this article by Aaron Bertrand [`What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: Thanks for your input on that one.